# Is there a way to fix error with user32.dll on Linux with pdfsharp project?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, pdfsharp

i have application with pdf generator. I'm using a pdfsharp lib.
On my local machine (**windows**) everything works fine but when i deploy app on my **linux** machine I get:

> Unable to load shared library 'user32.dll'

Is there a way to overcome this or there are any workarounds?

Answer (score -2):

PDFSharp doesn't support Linux now. Try to use .Net Core port for PDFSharp:

https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCorePdf